# Using boost memory pool in class

Tags: c++, memory, boost, pool

I tried to declare a memory pool in my class.

But the compiler shows some basic error like missing ')' before ';'

or syntax error : 'sizeof'

It works well if I used the pool as local variable but I really want to make it live with the class.

What's wrong about my usage?

Here is the class, the MAX_OBJ is a const

```
class CData
{
public:
 CData(void);
 ~CData(void);
private:
 boost::pool m_Pool(sizeof(DWORD) * MAX_OBJ);
};
```

Comment: Compiler also shows **where** the error is. It would be useful to know that as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it as anything to do with `boost::pool`.

But this line:

```
boost::pool m_Pool(sizeof(DWORD) * MAX_OBJ);
```

Should probably be:

```
boost::pool m_Pool;
```

And your constructor should then be:

```
CData::CData() :
  m_Pool(sizeof(DWORD) * MAX_OBJ)
{
}
```

You cannot construct members in the class **declaration**. You can just say: "My class has a member named `m_Pool` whose type is `boost::pool`."

You then specify in one or several constructor(s), how this member is initialized.

Comment: @Judarkness: You're welcome. I just wasted 10 minutes to find a missing `;` in my own code so I guess we all do basic errors at some point ;)